# Python passing variables through functions

Tags: python

I have been learning python for 2 days.
So I am making this program which generates different numbers, and adds them to a string.
I have a function for getting the random numbers:

```
def GetRandomNumbers():
    random_number = random.choice(zero_to_nine)
    two_random_number = random.choice(zero_to_nine)
    three_random_number = random.choice(zero_to_nine)
    four_random_number = random.choice(zero_to_nine)
```

//

```
def SettingVariables():
    first_combination = ("__asm _emit " + zero + ("x") + random_number + " " + "/")
    two_first_combination = ("__asm _emit " + zero + ("x") + two_random_number + " " + "/")
    three_first_combination = ("__asm _emit " + zero + ("x") + three_random_number + " " + "/")
    four_first_combination = ("__asm _emit " + zero + ("x") + four_random_number + " " + "/")
```

And then when I attempt to use theese generated variables in a different function where theese numbers are added onto text it is unidentified. I know it has something to do with global variables, but I would need some explaining.

Comment: Could you extend you question with full code of your program?

Comment: Perhaps `GetRandomNumbers()` should return a value?

Comment: Functions have their own scope, you cannot access objects that are declared in a separate "scope." Here is a good resource for learning about scopes: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp

Comment: https://pastebin.com/BYyiM6T2

Comment: Hey there, you probably won't succeed learning a programming language without a course or studying literature, but that should not keep you from doing so. A fantastic text book (and even free) for learning Python is [Think Python](https://greenteapress.com/wp/think-python/). I recommend doing all of the excercises!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Propably you should return values from your first function:

```
def GetRandomNumbers():
    ... # get your numbers
    return random_number, two_random_number, ...
```

Then you can parse these numbers as an argument to your second function:

```
def SettingVariables(first_num, second_num, third_num): ...
```

You could set a global variable like this (this is not recommended):

```
global var
var = 1
```

Your code could look like this:

```
def GetRandomNumbers():
    random_number = random.choice(zero_to_nine)
    two_random_number = random.choice(zero_to_nine)
    three_random_number = random.choice(zero_to_nine)
    four_random_number = random.choice(zero_to_nine)
    return random_number, two_random_number, three_random_number, four_random_number 

def SettingVariables(random_number, two_random_number, three_random_number, four_random_number):
    first_combination = ("__asm _emit " + zero + ("x") + random_number + " " + "/")
    two_first_combination = ("__asm _emit " + zero + ("x") + two_random_number + " " + "/")
    three_first_combination = ("__asm _emit " + zero + ("x") + three_random_number + " " + "/")
    four_first_combination = ("__asm _emit " + zero + ("x") + four_random_number + " " + "/")

# later in the program
nums = GetRandomNumbers()
SettingVariables(nums[0], nums[1], nums[2], nums[3]) # could also use *nums
```

*Note that your SettingVariables function should also return the "combinations". You then can use the same principle*

Comment: Using `global` as the first option is a bad advice

Comment: please don't advice using `global` like this

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting that you're function names contains keyword `get` and `set`. These are concept familiar to classes.
You may consider define some classes here.
An example would be

```
class RandomNumbers:
        def __init__(self, zero_to_nine):
            random_number = random.choice(zero_to_nine)


class Variables:
    def __init__(self, random_numbers):
        self.first_combination = ("__asm _emit " + zero + ("x") + random_numbers.random_number + " " + "/")
        ...
```

Then you can do like this:

```
random_numbers = RandomNumbers()
variables = Variables(random_numbers)
print(variables.first_combination)
```

[edit]

I suggested classes as it seems that you'are using functions as initializers. They are quite similar to what in OOP are object constructors.
This would avoid the need for declaring all a bunch of variables outside of the function, update them an returning from the function.

Comment: How does that similar to what OP is trying to do? I don't see the connection to the question, can you expand?